# Find a char that equals an input

Tags: c, string, char

In the code below I take the input from the user and then I find the digit that was introduced by comparing it to every other digit.

---

This my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int i = 0;
    int input;

    printf("Input a digit: \n");
    scanf("%d", &input);

    for(; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if(i == input)
        {
            printf("Your input is %d\n", i);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

How do I check for a letter instead? Say the user inputs letter G, and I take that in a loop to compare it to every other character until I find the one it equals to?

Comment: Guess what, the number that user inputted is... `input`. Why do you need a loop?

Comment: That's not the question that I need answered. But just so that you know, it's so I can calculate the time complexity it takes to try every combination of number/letters to crack a password.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pretty much the same code you already have, just scan for a `char`:

```
char input;
scanf("%c", &input);
```

To check the input, use what fits your expectations best. A `switch` is probably a solid choice:

```
switch (input) {
case 'G':
    printf("G was received\n");
    break;
default:
    printf("Uninteresting character %c was received\n", input);
}
```

Comment: checking every letter of the alphabet seems a bit tedious. My question is how do I compare a letter to others in order to match.

Comment: `input == 'x'`? Just use the comparison operator. If you have different actions for all letters of the alphabet, there is not really a way around tedious work. Switch, if/else, maybe even a lookup table using the integer values of the chars, ... It depends on your use-case.